# Python: how do I check if two arrays may be added?

Tags: python, numpy

```
# *-* coding: utf-8 *-*

import numpy as np
import scipy as sc

A = np.array([[1,1], [1,2], [3,1]])
B = np.array([[2,3], [3,2], [1,4]])

print (A==B).all()
print np.array_equal(A, B)
print np.array_equiv(A, B)
print np.allclose(A, B)
```

But they just say "False", but I can still add those two arrays. I have to check if an addition/multiplication is allowed (dimension?) and if not, I have to give out an error.

Comment: ...What? You want to check dimensions?? When you directly try to add arrays with unequal dimensions, numpy would throw error.

Comment: You can `try` [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/3.5/glossary.html#term-eafp) `except` you probably don't know what it is (yet).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

A = np.array([[1, 1], [1, 2], [3, 1]])
B = np.array([[2, 3], [3, 2], [1, 4]])
C = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4]])

# same shapes --> operations are not a problem
print(A+B)
print(A*B)

# shapes differ --> numpy raises ValueError
print(A+C)
print(A*C)
```

The ValueError raised by numpy is like the following:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,2) (2,2)

As you can see, the shapes are checked by `numpy` before doing any array operation.

However, if you want to do that manually or want to catch the exception raised by `numpy` you can do something like this:

```
# prevent numpy raising an ValueError by prooving array's shapes manually before desired operation
def multiply(arr1, arr2):
    if arr1.shape == arr2.shape:
        return arr1 * arr2
    else:
        print('Shapes are not equal. Operation cannot be done.')

print(multiply(A, B))
print(multiply(A, C))

# prevent numpy raising an ValueError by prooving array's shapes manually before desired operation
def add(arr1, arr2):
    if arr1.shape == arr2.shape:
        return arr1 + arr2
    else:
        print('Shapes are not equal. Operation cannot be done.')

print(add(A, B))
print(add(A, C))


# catch the error / exception raised by numpy and handle it like you want to
try:
    result = A * C
except Exception as e:
    print('Numpy raised an Exception (ValueError) which was caught by try except.')
else:
    print(result)
```

Answer (score 3):

To check whether the shapes will match for doing an addition, the trick will be dealing with broadcasting, since **broadcasting allows for the adding of arrays with unequal shapes**.  To check this then, one could use [`np.broadcast`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast.html).

Here's an example:

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
b = np.array([1, 2, 3])

a + b  # raises value error
np.broadcast(a, b)  # raise value error

a + b[:,None]   # does the addition with broadcasting
np.broadcast(a, b[:,None])   # returns a valid broadcast object
```

If `a` and `b` have the same shape and can be directly added, `np.broadcast` will also return a valid object without raising an exception.